# Convexity of a special kind of set

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, matrix-analysis

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a separable Hilbert space and $T\in B(\mathcal{H})$. Is the following set convex
\begin{align}
\{\langle Te_1,e_2\rangle:\{e_1,e_2\} \text{ are orthonormal set in } \mathcal{H}\}?
\end{align}

---

Could you please suggest to me some references in case this exists in the literature? I am not able to show it on my own.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Take
$$
T = \pmatrix{ 0 & 1\\ -1& 0}.
$$
Let $e_1=\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2}$, $e_2=\pm \pmatrix{-x_2\\x_1}$, then
$$
\langle Te_1,e_2\rangle = \pm 1,
$$
so the set in question is equal to $\{-1,+1\}$, which is not convex.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, here $\mathcal{H}$ is complex Hilbert space. So there are many more choices of $e_1,e_2$ than you mentioned. However in all cases, it seems $\langle Te_1, e_2\rangle$ will land only on the unit circle in the complex plane and hence it is not convex.

Comment: I feel that your example is not providing a counter-example since we are considering Hilbert space over $\mathbb{C}$. Let  $e_1=\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2}$. Suppose $e_2$ be a unit vector with $\langle e_2,e_1\rangle=0$. Then $e_2=e^{i\theta}\pmatrix{\overline{x_2}\\-\overline{x_1}}$ where $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$. Then $\langle Te_1,e_2\rangle=e^{-i\theta}(x_1^2+x_2^2)$. So if we varry now $e_1$, we will get closed unit disc, which is convex.